# Back button - skip anchors

Tags: javascript, url, anchor

I have a typical ajax-style dynamic content setup: click a link, change anchor in address bar, and load new content.  When user clicks the back button, it cycles through all the anchors - as expected.

Is there a way (using JavaScript I'm assuming) to make the back button go to the previous page, and 'ignore' all the anchors?

Answer (score 5):

Count the stages the user pass and use

```
history.back(X);
```

or

```
history.go(-1*X);
```

in order to go back X pages/anchors.

Answer (score 1):

First, to make sure Im understanding, you have named your AJAX bookmarks the same as IDs in your DOM elements? If so, anyway to undo this? You can trick it not to go down, but this is kludgy way of doing it. Instead you should have a ID like `#somepage` and AJAX urls like `#!/somepage` this way they don't get confused. Also, people like Google will not know normal `#id`s are hash URLs, but doing `#!/` gives Google a clue.

Now, if you want to do it using a `#!/` method you need a timer for older browsers (<=IE7) But for "modern" browsers IE8, FF, and Chrome you can use the onhashchange JS property like:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){ console.log('hash has changed') };
```

Then, if you want to support older browsers you need to do something a little more advanced. You need to do:

```
var currentPage = '';
setTimeout(function(){
  if(currentPage !== window.location.hash){
    console.log('hash has changed');
    currentPage = window.location.hash
  }
},500);
```

In both examples you need to replace the `console.log()`s with a function of your own that triggers the "change page" event.

To stop the scrolling you could add:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
  if (window.location.hash == "" || window.location.hash == "#"){ return false; }
  //rest of your code here!
};
```

The return false will prevent the scrolling. This should work in the timer as well.

More Information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288209(VS.85).aspx
http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs

Answer (score 0):

```js
location.replace(document.referrer)
```

this works for me. depending on your purpose, you can use it in the "onclick" or add some additional conditions via JavaScript e.g. if the referrer is empty
See:
[In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)