# Why is the http referer not showing?

Tags: php, http

I'm using this code wanting to display the url used to access this page:

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo ($referer);
?>
```

So when I've got this code in file index.php, put it onder www.mysite.com/index.php and I go to www.mysite.com, it should display 'www.mysite.com', shouldn't it?

When I use it though is displays nothing. Not locally on Mamp and also not online. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only if you're coming from another page. If you load it directly in the address bar or from a bookmark it will be empty.

Comment: because you have no referer. Set it inside another file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what cases will HTTP\_REFERER be empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty). Are you clicking a link to go from the first page to the second?

Comment: @j08691 if I am not mistaken, it won't be blank, instead it won't even be set.

Comment: Aha, I understand. The reason I wanted to use it was as a Flash mail form php script. So when I've got a Flash mail form on www.mysite.com, fill it in and click on send it accesses this php script. But that php script can only be used when the data was send at www.mysite.com (so where the Flash file is). So I can't use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; in this case?

Comment: Already fount it: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Comment: @jiggy1965 - See my response. Also, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` may not work as you want it to on nginx. It will always show the first defined alias for a given virtual host, regardless of which was used to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` tells you where you came from, not the page you're loading. If you want to show www.mysite.com, you're probably looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

If you want the full URL used to access the page, you're probably after `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

To make it easier to understand, these would be the variable values^ if you clicked a link from http://www.mysite.com/index.php to http://www.mysite.com/anotherpage.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = "http://www.mysite.com/index.php"
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = "www.mysite.com"
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/anotherpage.php"
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "www.mysite.com/anotherpage.php"
```

Hope this helps, the [full documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) on PHP `$_SERVER` reserved variables may help you more.

*^ Not all browsers set the `HTTP_REFERER` variable. It is optional in the RFC and as such you shouldn't rely on it being there to do any functionality.*

Answer (score 4):

The referer header is an **optional** header the browser sends when requesting a page, informing the server of the **previous** page it came from. So for the first page you type into the browser, there will be no referer. After you click on a link from one page to another, there *may* be a referer set.