# Back button via JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, web, back

This might be a nit-picking question, but still...

I'm going to have a "back" button/link on a 404 page. AFAIK it can be implemented with JavaScript `history.go(-1)` or with PHP using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

My question: what are pros and cons for one over the other?

Comment: In some cases, a browser in paranoid security mode or with some specific web clients you may not get `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: and in some you might not have JavaScript enabled...

Comment: i would suggest $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']...

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to set a session variable (ie. PREVIOUS_REQUEST) on every request. This is the only sure method of retaining that information. This takes some work on your side, but atleast it's a sure bet.

The javascript history might be prohibited due to extreme security settings in the browser (ie. disabled javascript).

The `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value is also supplied by the browser, so this being filled is also not guaranteed.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` could still be your best option, but do keep in mind its restrictions which you can find here: 
[In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty?lq=1)