# Using PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] Without Recognizing Parameters

Tags: php, get, http-referer

I'm using an if statement along with PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to check if users came from the home page and perform some functions if they did:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == htttp://www.example.com {
//some code
}
```

The problem is that the homepage will sometimes be passing GET variables in the URL and PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] method considers a URL with a GET variable as a different URL and therefore won't trigger the if function unless the user comes from the home page without passing a GET variable.

I'd like to trigger the if statement when someone comes from the home page regardless of whether a GET variable is passed, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sidenote: Using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not always reliable.

Comment: already covered in [in what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: @Fred-ii- is right, as per usual. Also, It's not always safe, either, [see why](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_referer_field_for_authentication_or_authorization).

Comment: Fictional attack possibilities: http://mixedbit.org/referer.html

Comment: @JackWilliams I don't always get it right, but I try ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into using a different method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to check if `HTTP_REFERER` *starts with* the URL you want:

`if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'http://www.example.com') === 0)) {`

Answer (score 3):

@EmilyShepherd's answer should work.

This, though, would check for just the domain. This is advantageous because some sites allow the omitting of (www.) and others may even be reachable through both (https://) and (http://).

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'example.com')) {/*If refer contains example.com*/}
```

As an aside, be mindful that refers can be easily spoofed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using this

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$data = parse_url($url);
$referer= $data['host'];

if($referer== 'www.example.com') {
    // Some codes here
}

/*
var_dump($data);
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.example.com
    [path] => /path/to/
    [query] => here=there
)
*/
```

With this, you can even extract paths and query string of the referer.

NOTE: If your scheme could be either `http` of `https`, it would be better to just extract the host name which would be `www.example.com` for matching.