# PHP PNG image on other sites

Tags: php, png

I have a php script that dynamically creates a png image. That image can be used on other sites. Is there any way to detect where my image is used in this php script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use  the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to see the referrer of the request.

Comment: __Note:__ This [isn't always available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty).