# About PHP form , redirection

Tags: php, forms

Suppose my Form codes look like this

URL : `localhost/my-url.php`

```
<form action="hello.php">
...bla bla bla
</form>
```

I will process the data in hello.php and i want to redirect to user to same url  after processing (according to above example)

```
localhost/my-url.php
```

I know we can use header but i don't know how to get that url from which form was submited :(

Googled but didn't found any use full.

Thanks.

Comment: pass the URL as a hidden input with the form or even better, try using ajax

Comment: You can give the previous page name in hidden value And can use that in header in next page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a hidden value in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lastUrl" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" />
```

You now have the URL in `$_POST['lastUrl']` data. You need to do it that complicated because `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` is send by the browser, and not all of them do this reliable.

Comment: about security? will i face problem if user sets their data?

Comment: @user3703850 if the user modifies the form, you receive modified data.

Comment: Well you would redirect them to another url. But there is no harm in that, they could have just as easily inputted the address in their browser themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You should put a hidden field in your form and set its value to current page url.

Then you submit the form and get the value of hidden field.

Then you can redirect user to hidden field (which is actually a URL of the page where you are submitting form) by using javascript or php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
 $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

to get the original URL where the form was posted from.

Remember to escape it, if you use it however. ]

Alternatively, you can process the form using AJAX, send process things (redirection) client-side.

Note that form data can be changed and intercepted if you wish to send the URL of the page as form data.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is transmitted by the browser. And not all of them do this!

Comment: @colburton whilst true, it's mostly reliable and somewhat secure.

Comment: I do not think, "mostly" and "somewhat" are going to cut it.

Comment: is is dependent on browser??

Comment: it's more secure than putting the data in the form itself. I say mostly because most browsers do send the data, but it is stripped out by intermediaries.

Comment: @user3703850 yes it is dependent on browser.

Comment: Thanks just want to know if major browser like moz,chorme,safari and some mobile browser support or not?

Comment: @user3703850 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: @bear: `"it's more secure than putting the data in the form itself"` - How so?  Both are sent from the client.  Both can be modified by the client, or omitted entirely.  How is one "more secure" than another?  At least with a form value the code is making an explicit assertion about what the behavior should be.  With the referrer header the code just assumes something which may not be true.

Comment: @David maybe I should clarify. Both are just as bad as each other. However, why would one make it easier to change? user3703850 could use both and determine one or the other.