# Preventing adding link to another link

Tags: php, mysql, url

Hello I'm currently working with php to generate a menu with a own build CMS system.

I'm making a dynamic link with : `$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."/";`
Than I'm adding `. $row_menu['page_link']` from the database. At first it works perfect:

as example =

```
$row_menu['page_link'] = page2;

$url . $row_menu['page_link'];
```

it will return as example : http://example.com/page2

But when I click again, it adds page2 again like : http://example.com/page2/page2

How do i prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because at first time your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be like `http://example.com` but when the user click on the link then the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would become `http://example.com/page2`.That's why it is appending two times.

Instead you can use `HTTP_REFERER` like

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$row_menu['page_link'];
```

Considering that your `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will results `http://example.com`.Also you can try like

```
$protocol = 'http';
$url = $protocol .'//'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'. $row_menu['page_link'];
```

Comment: Yes but how do i prevent it from doing that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

http-referer cant be trusted

Comment: I think you will have problem if you try to use this $url in a page like this: http://localhost/something/. If I understand, in this case your need $url to be http://localhost/something/page2. This $url will give you http://localhost/page2

Comment: @GabrielMoretti here the $row_menu['page_link'] = page2; and it is only appended with the `HOST`

Comment: I tought that he needed to use REQUESTED_URI to generate links according to the currently path.. in this case, i think your solution wont work

Comment: @GabrielMoretti I think it wont include host

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_URI will give you whatever comes after example.com, so leave that out all together.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . $row_menu['page_link'];
```

You can find a full list of the $_SERVER references [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$requested_uri = $_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI'];
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri_segments = explode('/',$requested_uri);

$row_menu['page_link'] = 'page2';
if($row_menu['page_link'] == $uri_segments[sizeof($uri_segments)-1]) {
    array_pop($uri_segments);
}

$uri = implode('/',$uri_segments);

$url = 'http://'.$host.'/'.$uri.'/'.$row_menu['page_link'];

echo $url;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when i try this, the pages shows up blanc, i added a semicolon after ['page_link'], but that didn't solve the problem.