# hotlinking prevention via htaccess doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysecondsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://imgur.com/gallery/tASrcBw [NC,R,L]
```

I'm using wordpress and pasted above code into my htaccess but still I'm seeing other sites using my hosted images. Why?

Comment: Looks fine to me, maybe try removing the `^http(s)?://` part of your regexes? I'm not sure, but it should still work as expected without it there.

Comment: that is optional , I don't thin that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your current rewrite configuration allows anyone to directly access your image by typing its  URL in their address bar and the `HTTP_REFERER` header [will not be set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880668), making your first condition fail.

```
# Check other conditions and rewrite rule only if %{HTTP_REFERER} is NOT empty
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```

Your conditions are implicitly `AND` unless you use the `[OR]` flag. When the first condition fails, the other conditions will not be tested and the redirection to your imgurl message never happens.

#### Fix:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If this condition is true, skip the other conditions and redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]

# Redirect to imgurl only if image requests are NOT from own site references
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysecondsite.com [NC]

# Do the redirection for images
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://i.imgur.com/tASrcBw.png [NC,R=302,L]
```