# Display Different Phone # based referring page (PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, referrer, http-referer

I need your help.

I want to show different phone # based on what page (within same site) user came from.

Everthing will take place within same website.

All users will come to same page - misite.com/phone.php

Example:

- If user came from misite.com/page1.php, show phone number 1
- If user came from misite.com/page2.php, show phone number 2
- If user came from misite.com/page3.php, show phone number 3

Else, show default phone number (if I do not list a specific page).

I guess it will ba a if / elseif statement, but i'm not a coder and don't know how to sturcture it correctly.

I'm looking for example of code please.

I also thing I will need to us to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` for this.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: " but i'm not a coder and don't know how to sturcture it correctly" you either need to learn or hire some one,

Comment: You won't always get a referrer,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: Is this all on the same site?? Or from one site to another site?
I ask because sessions or cookies will work if all from same site..

Comment: @Dagon I took PHP / JS / SQL class, but am not good enough to structure this. Coding is not my full time job. Also this is the site for people to ask questions and get answers - not for comments like yours - it's not helpful at all. I know I can hire someone but it will take much longer than asking a question here.

Comment: instead of using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, consider adding a parameter to the phone page using query string ( e.g. `example.com/phone.php?phoneId=1` )

Comment: @Jason - yes, all on the same site - updated Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF all these pages are on the same site, I would use sessions.

On each page, set a session to something you can test against later.
On one page:

```
//Start session first   
session_start();
//Then choose a keyword to put in the single quotes & have it equal a unique number
    $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
```

On another page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['page'] = 2;
```

On another page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['page'] = 3;
```

Then on the page where you want to display a phone number, do a test:

```
session_start();
switch ($_SESSION['page']) {
    case 0:
        $phone="555-555-5555";
        break;
    case 1:
        $phone="555-555-5556";
        break;
    case 2:
        $phone="555-555-5557";
        break;
    default:
        $phone="555-555-5558";
}
```

Then, echo $phone

Quick note, some shared hosting providers have issues using sessions out of the box, not sure why but I have run into it.

Comment: so if user came form somepage.html  which is not listed in switch statement, how do I show default number?

Comment: add:  default:
       $phone="number"

Comment: If user came from `misite.com/aboutus.html` how do I list that in switch statement?

Comment: On aboutus.html, set a session to a unique number not used on any other page... then add that to the switch statement, use corresponding phone number.

Comment: how would I do that (set session)?

Comment: First, you must start sessions with: session_start(); THEN $_SESSION['page'] = a number

Comment: so I don't ask you a series of lead-on questions, can you provide sample code? For example I don't understand this part `switch ($_SESSION['page']) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75757/discussion-between-jason-and-roofing-calculator).