# How to hide referrer for users exiting my site?

Tags: php, apache, http, web, referrer

so I want to find a way using PHP/.htaccess so that when a user visiting my site types a site in the URL bar it doesn't show the referrer. I know services like anonym can do this for url links but is it possible to do this for users to go to new site via the URL bar?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. When a user goes to another site by typing the address in URL bar ([and in many other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)), no HTTP Referer information is sent to that site.

Comment: Ah, did not know that ty for the info. What about if they search through the custom search engine of the browser? Any way to avoid referrer when using that?

Comment: It's the same concept. According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer): `The HTTP referer is an HTTP header field that identifies the address of the webpage that linked to the resource being requested`. When someone searches through the browser's custom search engine, this is not coming from your site, so it will not add your site's address to the http referer field.