# urlReferrer is comming null in MVC Post controller Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm Posting form from one mvc application A to another mvc application B.

In B Action Method I'm getting the urlReferer as null.

Application A Code:

```
 private string BuildPostForm(string Url, string PostData)
        {
            try
            {

                string formId = "__PostForm";

                StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
                strForm.Append(string.Format("<form id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" action=\"{1}\" method=\"POST\">", formId, Url));
                string MID = "9820359248";
                strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + "merchantRequest" + "\" value=\"" + PostData + "\">");
                strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + "MID" + "\" value=\"" + MID + "\">");
                //if (PostData != null)
                //{
                //    foreach (string key in PostData)
                //    {
                //        strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + "\" value=\"" + PostData[key] + "\">");
                //    }
                //}
                //  strForm.Append("<div id=\"loading\"><p class=\"top1 loading-txt\"> Processing Payment </p><img id=\"loading-image\" src=\"../../Images/ajax-loader.gif\"   alt=\"Loading...\" /><p class=\"top2 loading-txt-bottom\">Please do not press on refresh button</p></div>");
                strForm.Append("<div class=\"wrapper\"><div class=\"login_wrap loading_wrap\"><div class=\"logo\"> </div><br><p class=\"top1 loading-txt\"> Processing Payment  </p><div class=\"sk-spinner sk-spinner-wandering-cubes loading_tp\"><div class=\"sk-cube1\"></div><div class=\"sk-cube2\"></div></div><p  class=\"top2 loading-txt-bottom\">Please do not press on refresh button</p></div></div>");
                strForm.Append("</form>");
                strForm.Append("<link  rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../../Content/css/PinePGRedirect.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>");
                strForm.Append("<link  rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../../Content/css/loader.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>");
                StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
                strScript.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
                strScript.Append(string.Format("var v{0}=document.{0};", formId));
                strScript.Append(string.Format("v{0}.submit();", formId));
                strScript.Append("</script>");

                return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }

     public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var strHtml = "";

                strHtml = BuildPostForm(m_Url, m_strPostData);

            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(strHtml);
        }
```

Application B Code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri uri1 =  HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
               string str =  Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
return View();
}
```

Getting uri1 and str as null.

Comment: Are these your cases:
- switched from a https URL to a http URL.
- switched from a https URL to a different https URL.
- has security software installed (antivirus/firewall/etc) which strips the referrer from all requests.
- is behind a proxy which strips the referrer from all requests.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Answer (score 0):

Because your application A is not hosting.