# Cannot get referral URL PHP

Tags: php, url, if-statement

I am trying to get the URL of the site which referred the user to the site with the script on it.

***Here is the script I am using:***

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $ref_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //get referrer
}else{
    $ref_url = 'none'; // show failure message
}
echo $ref_url;
```

The issue I am having is that no matter what site I come to the main site from, I always get  *'none'* echoed. What is causing this and how can I make the script actually get the referrers URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what cases will HTTP\_REFERER be empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did research this before posting and found this post, however this does not help me, as far as I can see my circumstances meet none of the requirements for it to be empty