# how to get referrer from ContainerRequestContext object

Tags: java, rest, jersey

How to get referrer URL from `ContainerRequestContext` object.

Please find the code snippet below,

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
   ApplicationUser user = (ApplicationUser) CacheManagerBase.getInstance().getApplicationUserCache().getCurrentUser();
   requestContext.setSecurityContext(new UserContext(user));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple of different options, but the simplest is

```
String referrer = requestContext.getHeaderString("referer");
```

That might return `null` if the header isn't set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case i got to make it more secured and i got to take the actual referrer using the REST jersey framework and inturn J2EE, instead of me sending the referrer and fetching it.

Answer (score 0):

Referer will not be available in all the cases, mentioned in the POST below,

[In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)