# How to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] correctly in php?

Tags: php, redirect, http-referer

Lets say i have two pages `page1.php` and `page2.php` and i want `page2.php` to be displayed only if it is redirected form `page1.php` and i inserted this code to `page2.php`

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "page1.php")
{
    //keep displaying page2.php
}else{
    //if it is not redirected from page1.php
    header('Location:page1.php')
    //redirect the user back to page1.php 
}
```

this code worked fine until i have a form and a submit button on `page2.php` when the submit button is clicked the page refreshes which means the `HTTP_REFERER` will change to `page2.php` so my `if statement` fails and it takes me back to `page1.php` i don't want that to happen. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The referer is an user provided value and shouldn't be relied on as it can be manipulated or omitted at all. Instead use sessions, set a session variable on page1.php and check for it on page2.php.

Comment: @CharlesAddis i added the code but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `HTTP_REFERER`:

1. It's fairly simple to manipulable in browser.
2. Some users might have security settings in their browser to not send this header at all.
3. It's not accessible over `HTTPS`.
4. Some proxies strip this header from the request
5. Added - See answer to [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)

---

As  Charlotte Dunois stated in the comment, better set session value before sending the form and then check it on page2.

**page1.php:**

```
$_SESSION[ 'display_page2' ] = TRUE;
//rest of the content
```

**page2.php:**

```
if ( (isset( $_SESSION[ 'display_page2' ] ) && $_SESSION[ 'display_page2' ] === TRUE ) || isset( $_POST[ 'some_form_input' ] ) ) {
  //keep displaying page2.php
} else {
  header('Location:page1.php');
  exit;
}
```

With `isset( $_POST[ 'some_form_input' ] )`, you can check whether the form has been sent (via POST method).

When needed, you can unset the session with `unset( $_SESSION[ 'display_page2' ] );` or by setting it to different value.

Comment: Adding the or operator doesn't solve the problem it will allow the user if they use the url to get page2.php

Comment: The referer is still accessible over HTTPS.

Comment: Coming to this post years after, but I just wanted to show that 1st condition can be simplified by using `empty` method that check both isset and to be TRUE : 

`if (!empty($_SESSION['display_page2'])`

Comment: @pti_jul Yes, it could. Just note that some linters don't allow using `empty()` because it's ambiguous.

Comment: @PetrHejda OK thanks, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 4):

I advise against using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as it can be easily spoofed.

Instead , you could set a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) when they load page 1 using `setcookie("page1", 1);` *before* any markup is output. Then check for it on page 2 using

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['page1']))
{
    //keep displaying page2.php
}else{
    //if it is not redirected from page1.php
    header('Location:page1.php')
    //redirect the user back to page1.php 
}
```

By not specifying the expiry date the cookie will expire when the browser is closed. In this situation, using cookies also makes for much more readable code to others.

Comment: This is exactly the approach I would suggest, surafel. You'll have much better results using cookies and it can be used in many different ways! Check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp for a basic example.

Comment: @jarmerson Please link the php.net documentation page to `setcookie` instead of [w3fools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @Cha I already have, he was just helping others find another example. The official ones aren't always that useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "page1.php") || (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="page2.php"))
{
    //keep displaying page2.php
}else{
    //if it is not redirected from page1.php
    header('Location:page1.php');
    //redirect the user back to page1.php 
}

?>
```

if the referrer is not page 1 you could check the condition if referrer = page2 and post is submitted.
or check if the referrer is page1 or post is submitted.
this is a possibility to avoid your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/* 
    this page allows links from the following pages

    public.php?id=links
    private.php?id=links

don't allow if visitors come from anywhere else

this example would only work if I used the entire URL in the 'if' statement 
*/

$referringpage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if ( $referringpage == "http://www.example.com/public.php?id=links" ) {
$pass = "yes";
} elseif ( $referringpage == "http://www.example.com/private.php?id=links" ) {
$pass = "yes";
} else {
$pass = "no";
}


if ( $pass == "yes" ) {
// do the function this page was made to do
} 

header( "Location: http://www.example.com/public.php?id=links" );

?>
```