# CodeIgniter - How to redirect user after login, to the previous attempted route

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, referrer

With CodeIgniter framework, I have an admin page inside `AdminController`, inside its constructor I put a check if user is not logged-in then redirect to the login page.

And In `LoginController` after successful login, I want user to redirect to the previous admin page.

From different examples I tried:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$this->session->set_userdata('redirect_back', $this->agent->referrer());
```

And also

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

But both are returning me empty string.

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: So many ways to do this.  [However, I would not use `http_referer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36240257/594235).  Have you searched yet?  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcodeigniter%5D+redirect+after+login

Comment: Finally I did as suggested by @Karlo's answer. I not get idea why this user_agent library not working as expected, may be I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AdminController` file, before redirecting to `LoginController`, save the current url to a session variable:

```
$referrer_value = current_url().($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!=""?"?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']:"");
$this->session->set_userdata('login_referrer', $referrer_value);
// redirect to login page
```

In your `LoginController`, on successful login, check if session 'login_referrer' has value. If it has then redirect using the value of that.

```
if($this->session->userdata('login_referrer')!=""){
    $tmp_referrer = $this->session->userdata('login_referrer');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('login_referrer');
    redirect($tmp_referrer);
}
```

You may need to call the following to load the required library and helper for the above code to run successfully.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('session');
```

Comment: Thanks @KarloKokkak, Thats how I used to do with my .net applications. Here I was just trying to follow codeigniter user_agent library, and php server variables array, as it was suggested in some articles. At-the-end this trick did the job.