# Source of a redirect done with header()

Tags: php, header

How can I see the source of a redirect done with `header("location:....");`?
For example if I do an header from example.com, how can I see that it comes from example.com?

Comment: You can try `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240145/how-to-use-serverhttp-referer-correctly-in-php