# Retrieving Other language Links using WPML Language Code and Post ID retrieved from Post URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am building a Custom Language Selector page that displays all the languages enabled in WPML in a separate Page for changing languages instead of the Language Selector widget.

I am getting the previous page URL via

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

I am getting Post/page ID using the below function.

```
url_to_postid();
```

Then I have a foreach loop which returns the Language Code. I want to get the correct URL based on the Language code and Post ID.

I tried using the below code for getting this done but its not working as expected.

```
$previous_post_link = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', get_the_permalink( $last_visited_id ), $language_code );
```

This works partly. When I use this function, I get the URL of the Post ID based on the language code but the slug is not correct. "es" is the language code Below the URL is the URL of the Post ID that I send.

```
https://www.domainname.com/kontakt/
```

The actual Spanish version of this URL and the expected result is below.

```
https://www.domainname.com/es/contacto/
```

Instead, this displays the URL wrongly as

```
https://www.domainname.com/es/kontakt/
```

Can someone help me understand the issue and help me solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I would like to understand if using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] works fine as long as I am expecting it to work only for the internal URLs."_ - HTTP_REFERER is an optional header that may or may not be set by the client. You can't trust or rely on that header existing or being accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So this differs from browser to browser? Is this based on browser settings? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_REFERER'\] correctly in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240145/how-to-use-serverhttp-referer-correctly-in-php) - Read through that question and the answers and comments.

Comment: Hi @M.Eriksson , I have edited and removed the part of that question. Not sure why it's been Down voted as the main question is not regarding HTTP Referer.