# http_referer empty on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami

I'm trying to access the http_referer in a bitnami wordpress install on aws. It's returning an empty string even tho I'm loading the page from another page in the site, not by directly entering the url.

Same code worked before I moved the site to AWS.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bitnami WordPress Cloud Image doesn't block or strips the HTTP_REFERER. Apache and PHP are not configured to modify it.

I recommend you to take a look to the next SO case:
[In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)

There you'll find a bunch of possible reasons why it could be empty. The problem could be related with your browser or the Firewall configuration on your Server.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did not know about the HTTPS <-> HTTP issue with respect to HTTP_REFERER.