# Does any browser implementation uses full url path in Origin header in an ajax request?

Tags: browser, xmlhttprequest

I'm talking about a CORS preflight HTTP request by the OPTIONS method which is sent by default by the browser before the actual request. In that request is it possible to make Orgin header to include the full url path?

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1  
Host: example.com
Origin: http://www.example.com/blah
```

I want my page to send full url in Origin header. Is there any way to trick the browser to do so?

Comment: Isn't a `REFERER` (sic) header sent by default?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen see the new description.

Comment: Not possible, in my opinion.

Comment: As far as the Referer header, you can’t depend on it. Users can choose to have their browsers not send it http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader (and to suppress document.referrer too) , and there are lots of other conditions in which it may be empty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty/6880668#6880668 And the in browsers that support Referer Policy, authors can also cause the Referer header to be empty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty/28836003#28836003

Answer (score 1):

you can always pass this value on the ajax parameters using something like:

```
$.ajax(url, {
      fullOrigin: window.location.href
   }
)
```

like #Robby Cornelisse said - most servers will hold REFERER server variable with this value.

Comment: see the new description.

Comment: Second parameter in `jQuery.ajax()` is settings object. There is no `fullOrigin` key, jQuery will ignore it and it's value. For more information see [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Answer (score 1):

The browser will send a `REFERER` header containing the full URL with your AJAX request.

In the screenshot below, I just used the console to send an AJAX request from this page. Notice the **Referer** header.

[image: Referer header]

Comment: @t6chgeek I logged out before posting. Removed them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Origin is a scheme, domain and port parts of an URI by definition.

One option is to send current document URI to server using query part of request URI. You can use code below to change URI of every cross origin request on your page:

```
window.addLocation = function( uri ) {
  var parser = document.createElement('a');
  parser.href = uri;
  var and = parser.search ? "&" : "";
  parser.search = parser.search + and + "madeBy=" + window.location;
  return parser.href;
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", window.addLocation( originalUri ), true );
```

Note that current page URI may contain sensitive information, and that browser identifies HTTP Cache entries by URI including query.

For more information check:

- [Origin header page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) on MDN
- [Referer header section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) in HTTP 1.1 specification
- [URL Parsing gist](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561) by jlong
- [HTTP access control (CORS) page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on MDN