# How to allow a cross-origin request when the Origin header is null?

Tags: javascript, http, cors

### Scenario

We have some Javascript hosted by a third-party CMS service, and we have some data on a server under our control. When a user is accessing the CMS via a browser (and executing our Javascript), we would like to make a cross-origin `GET` request to our server and have the server respond with the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header so that the browser accepts the response.

### Problem

When we inspect requests going from the CMS to our server, the request's `Origin` header is set to `null`. So we can't set a value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` other than `*` to make the browser accept the response. We're not really sure why the value is `null`. The JS is executing in an environment that we don't fully control.

### Potential Solution

We're working under the assumption that the Origin will always be null, and there's nothing we can do to change it. The best solution we can come up with is defining a pre-shared secret. When the browser makes the cross-origin request, it adds a custom header with the secret. The server looks for that header, and if the secret matches, the server adds the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Is there a better, more secure way to handle this situation?

Comment: You can create a proxy endpoint on your server that will accept the request from your JS, and make a request to the third-party CMS service using `curl`

Comment: Why is the origin `null`? This would be the case if the requesting resource is `file:///...`

Comment: All requests by browser will have a Referer header

Comment: @Andreas So if you're correct, that mean that they can make no ajax request at all, right?

Comment: @AlonEitan We don't need to make a request to the CMS. We need to make a request from the CMS JS to our server.

Comment: @Andreas You're correct, but we're not running the JS from a file in this case.

Comment: FYI, `null` is part of the specification and you can return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`. That has all the same security implications as `*`, though.

Comment: As far as the Referer header, you can’t depend on it. Users can choose to have their browsers not send it http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader (and to suppress document.referrer too) , and there are lots of other conditions in which it may be empty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty/6880668#6880668. And in browsers that support Referer Policy, authors can also cause the Referer header to be empty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty/28836003#28836003.

Comment: @SamJones In current browsers, JavaScript running from a `file:` origin can make requests using XHR and the Fetch API and it’ll work. But I see you say the `null` cases you’re seeing come from requests made by code running at a CMS. In that case I’d guess the requests are made from sandboxed iframes that lack the `allow-same-origin` header. Otherwise, browsers also send `Origin: null` for requests from *any* non-http/https origins; for example, pages opened from `data:` URIs.

Comment: Another case where you’ll end up with `Origin: null` is for requests that get redirected across origins. For example, if from XHR in my JS I make a request to `http://example.com/api` and that gets redirected to `http://api.example.com`, then `Origin` will get set to `null` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the request `Referer` header which is set by the browser and use that for the response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value