# REFERER return nothing

Tags: php

I am trying to get the referer with `php` using:

```
var_dump($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

But it returns `NULL`.

I put this code in `sample.php`, This file linked in `index.php` and when I click on link, it shows `sample.php` file but referer returns `NULL`. What am I missing?

What I'm trying to do is, getting previous file name, I mean when I go to `sample.php` from a page, I want to get previous page file name.

I've worked with `referer` before, however I have not seen this result before. Any ideas?

Comment: `The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: And this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty