# Link to previous page if exists and is not an external link

Tags: wordpress, browser-history, http-referer

I want to create a go back button on a `single.php` in WordPress.
I know I can easily do that with `window.history.go(-1)` but in the case of the visitor come from another site, I want to redirect to the homepage of my site.

In other words: How can I know if the previous page is an internal link to my site? And if not, redirect to the homepage?

Comment: You could look into `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))` and check if your domain matches it, and then use header to redirect them accordingly

Comment: but it can be spoofed, and is not always set - basically it is up the the browser that your user is using.

Comment: check this answer, to see when referer will be empty : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty