# strange encoding to querystring

Tags: c#, encoding, request.querystring

i have created two aspx pages for the demo,

page1 - WebForm1.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="test" Width="100px" OnClick="btnClick_Click"/>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["text"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["text"].ToString()))
                txtTest.Text = "ö";
            else
                txtTest.Text = Request.QueryString["text"].ToString();
        }
    }

    public void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.location = '{0}';</script>", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("WebForm2.aspx?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtTest.Text))));
        response.End();
    }
```

page2 - WebForm2.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtResult" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="back" Width="50px" OnClick="btnBack_Click"/>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["text"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["text"].ToString()))
                txtResult.Text = "empty";
            else
                txtResult.Text = Request.QueryString["text"].ToString();
        }
    }

    public void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.location = '{0}';</script>", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("WebForm1.aspx?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtResult.Text))));
        response.End();
    }
```

and then i used Fiddler to track the web, clicked test button and then clicked back button.

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
6   200 HTTP    localhost:56484 /WebForm2.aspx?text=%c3%b6  835 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:12316          
8   200 HTTP    localhost:56484 /WebForm2.aspx?text=%u00f6  175 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:12316          
9   200 HTTP    localhost:56484 /WebForm1.aspx?text=%c3%b6  830 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:12316          
10  200 HTTP    localhost:56484 /WebForm1.aspx?text=%u00f6  175 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:12316          
11  200 HTTP    localhost:56484 /WebForm2.aspx?text=%c3%b6  834 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:12316
```

we could see the URL bodies have strange encoding, **why did %u00f6 generate? can it be back to %c3%b6?**

and when we were clicking back button to back to page1, its referrer became missing. Actually i think the strange encoding caused the issue, because when i used F12 Developer tools to change the action(from "%u00f6" to "%c3%b6"), and then clicked back button, the referrer was generated.

[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cylOX.png)

much appreciate to you if you can give the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding behavior is a standard. As per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-14).

**2.4.  When to Encode or Decode**

> Under normal circumstances, the only time when octets within a URI
> are percent-encoded is during the process of producing the URI from
> its component parts.  This is when an implementation determines which
> of the reserved characters are to be used as subcomponent delimiters
> and which can be safely used as data.  Once produced, a URI is always
> in its percent-encoded form.
>
> When a URI is dereferenced, the components and subcomponents
> significant to the scheme-specific dereferencing process (if any)
> must be parsed and separated before the percent-encoded octets within
> those components can be safely decoded, as otherwise the data may be
> mistaken for component delimiters.  The only exception is for
> percent-encoded octets corresponding to characters in the unreserved
> set, which can be decoded at any time.  For example, the octet
> corresponding to the tilde ("~") character is often encoded as "%7E"
> by older URI processing implementations; the "%7E" can be replaced by
> "~" without changing its interpretation.
>
> Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for
> percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that
> octet to be used as data within a URI.  Implementations must not
> percent-encode or decode the same string more than once, as decoding
> an already decoded string might lead to misinterpreting a percent
> data octet as the beginning of a percent-encoding, or vice versa in
> the case of percent-encoding an already percent-encoded string.

You can also use [www.urlencoder.org](https://www.urlencoder.org/) to see the expected url encoded output if you want to do some testing.

As to why the referrer became missing, you can take a look at [In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880668/6138713).

> It will/may be empty when the enduser
>
> - entered the site URL in browser address bar itself.
> - visited the site by a browser-maintained bookmark.
> - visited the site as first page in the window/tab.
> - clicked a link in an external application.
> - switched from a https URL to a http URL.
> - switched from a https URL to a different https URL.
> - has security software installed (antivirus/firewall/etc) which strips the referrer from all requests.
> - is behind a proxy which strips the referrer from all requests.
> - visited the site programmatically (like, curl) without setting the referrer header (searchbots!).

After some digging I saw this from the [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36).

**14.36 Referer**

> The Referer[sic] request-header field allows the client to specify,
> for the server's benefit, the address (URI) of the resource from which
> the Request-URI was obtained (the "referrer", although the header
> field is misspelled.) The Referer request-header allows a server to
> generate lists of back-links to resources for interest, logging,
> optimized caching, etc. It also allows obsolete or mistyped links to
> be traced for maintenance. The Referer field MUST NOT be sent if the
> Request-URI was obtained from a source that does not have its own URI,
> such as input from the user keyboard.

Checkout the last sentence of the paragraph, I believe that in your example you "changed" the encoding.

> i used F12 Developer tools to change the action(from "%u00f6" to
> "%c3%b6")

Comment: thanks John! i am reading and trying the first answer. From my sample, it wasnot in the list that caused the referrer missing. when i changed the action manually (from "%u00f6" to "%c3%b6") in the form, and then clicked back button, the referrer was returned.

Comment: If you're really interested in that you can check out the [Referrer Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/).