# Return to previous page

Tags: perl, http-referer

Let me start with 1) I know just enough to get myself in trouble most of the time and out of it occasionally. 2) I am stuck with a very old shopping cart, but it serves my purpose, and I am already 5 years past retirement age and have no desire to start from scratch (I'll leave that up to someone else). So.....

When someone adds something to the shopping cart, there is a "continue shopping" button (code below). It always used to (for YEARS) return them to the last page they viewed. Now it returns to index.html page instead (very annoying to the shopper if they want multiple things from the same page).

Tested on Firefox and Chrome - same results

`$ContinueShopURL` is null ('')

`$ErrMsgRedirect` and `$ErrMsgViewCart` are not index.html

`$ERRORMODE` is not 2

From my extremely limited understanding it is looking like `HTTP_REFERER` is not functioning.

Any thoughts?   Thanks!

```
if ($ContinueShopURL) {
    $previouspage = $ContinueShopURL;
} elsif ($frm{'previouspage'}) {
    $previouspage = $frm{'previouspage'};
} else {
    if ($ERRORMODE==2 && $ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'} =~ /$ErrMsgRedirect/i) {
        $previouspage = $ErrMsgViewCart;
    } else {
        if ($frm{'RET_URL'}) {
            $previouspage = $frm{'RET_URL'};
        } else {
            $previouspage = $ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought: Does HTTP_REFERER work with https ? It might be because the page is https, and it only works with http.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but it isn't https at that point.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it on another site, which is https and the cart is functioning correctly there. That site is newer, but the code is exactly the same, which now has me twice as confused.

Comment: Indentation is a good thing, you know.

Comment: Try printing some debug statement in that nest of if-statements and see which one triggers.

Comment: Valid, but I wanted to cut and paste lest I change something inadvertently. I didn't write the code.

Comment: Will do.   Thanks.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: Re "*it is looking like HTTP_REFERER is not functioning*", What does that means? Are you saying it's empty?

Comment: Misfit:  Thanks - a lot of good information there.

Comment: ikegami - I still have not had the chance to to the debugging TLP suggested. I'll know much better when I do.

Comment: I have not dived into this, but it might be worth checking out if the problem have something to do with new refer(r)er policy in Chrome (version 85 from August 2020) and I'm guessing other browsers too. More on that here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default