# Get information of site from wher user clicked our link using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a question please guide.

I want to know from which social account user click on my sites link.

For example: I shared my site links on Facebook and WhatsApp and now users are coming from these links. I want to know if user click my link from Facebook or WhatsApp, without passing any query parameters to link.

I tried `http_referrer`

Comment: what u tried so far? share it

Comment: Use Google analytics

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to know where the user came from.

Comment: I already tried this but its always empty

Comment: From what I know this variable can indeed be empty in some cases, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880668/19422491

Maybe your are in one of this cases?