# How I can detected referrer?

Tags: javascript, php, detection

The user followed the link, for example from a telegram application, how can I determine that it was a telegram without passing get parameters in URL?

I visit suit following the link from email, telegram. In  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` - it's empty.

Comment: You can't. You need to either pass a query parameter or have an alternative URL for telegram links (which can log and redirect the user to the main URL).

Comment: I hope this link helps you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: did you try [Document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) ?

Comment: You can set a cookie when the user clicks on a link. You would need to remember to unset it after recognising it so all subsequent requests weren't treated as telegrams. Alternatively, you could use a different port on your server for telegrams.